# Bold part of a url in markdown

Tags: hyperlink, markdown

I want to bold part of a url written in markdown.

> URL: http://google.com
>
> Intended result: http://**google**.com

In this example, I want to bold the word "google" inside the whole url. Here, I capitalized what I wanted to bold.

Related question: is there a way to prevent urls from turning into links?

I am processing this with a marked.js. I'm looking for something that will work in http://dillinger.io/

===== Part 2 =====

> URL: http://google.com
>
> Intended result: http://**google**.**com**

How do I also bold the .com part in addition to the google part?

Comment: I know I can do the following, but is there a more elegant way?

<a href="http://google.com/">http://<em>google</em>.com/ </a>

Comment: I guess this depends on where are you processing this markdown text. Here in SO you could paste this code on your post and you'll see that the second line would have the desired word bolded and would not be presented with an link

Comment: Okay, I clarified my question. Thanks. Amazingly, it works in SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work

```
[http://**example**.com](http://example.com).
```

Using http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus the above gives the HTML result:

```
<a href="http://example.com">http://<strong>example</strong>.com</a>
```

That is exactly what you want.

Comment: Hmm interesting. It works on dingus but not on dillinger.io (marked.js).  Is it possible to also do the "com" part of the url?

Comment: yeah. Any part you want to make bold enclose it in the double asterisk. That should work. Here is a link to the basic Markdown syntax: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using markdown and jekyll, and the markdown doc says you can't have any formatting between "ticks." I even tried it with a block and the asterisks still print as characters, because you can't put spaces in a URL and the formatting requires spaces to work. Even HTML commands print as characters ().